# Dividers in String Java

Tags: java, string, parsing, expression

Suppose a mathematical expression is given with any number of divisions / in it.

For example:

```
(x+2) / (1+ 1 / (x-2))
```

How can I output every divisor in the expression? For the above example the output would have to be:

```
1+1/(x-2)
x-2
```

Because there's a division by `1+1/(x-2)`, and that in turn contains a division by `x-2`.

I only get the first divisor, that is, the whole exprssion after the first /. How do I get all divisors?

Edit:  What he is requesting is to get all the divisors in the expression.

Comment: Can you exlain `lines in which there will be all dividers`?

Comment: can you edit your question with some more clarity

Comment: lol. check it again man, you have even changed the signs(operators), from + to -. may be you wanted something that is beyond mathematics.

Comment: First, you only give a requirement hoping to get the complete solution, this is not the topic of stackoverflow. Then of course, this explanation is what too short. This is not clear at all. So edit your question to add information and what you have tried please. See [ask]

Comment: @ZubairNabi No, it looks like he wants all the divisors. So first he'd need to get (1 + 1 / (x - 2)). That in turn has a divisor in it, namely (x - 2).

Comment: @G_H Yes, exactly

Comment: ok, got it. @G_H 
 Georgy: you can do that making the expression as String and then split it on "/", if that is what you want, i can post code for that in answer. let me know

Comment: Sure posting it as answer. give me a sec

Comment: @ZubairNabi Yes, it need

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear. Let me know if I misinterpreted your requirements. If you have a partially working solution, the key is probably to recursively apply the method to the result (the divisor) of a previous invocation. So after getting `1+1/(x-2)` you'd run the method again on that, and stop recursion if the result is empty (no division). Look into "recursion" and "expression parsing", you'll find plenty of resources. If this is not some assignment and you just need the results, there's probably some library out there that can do this for you.

Comment: `public static void main(String args[]){
  String exp= "(x+2) / (1+ 1 / (x-2))";
  
  while(exp != ""){
  String [] splitted= exp.split("/",2);
   
  exp=splitted[1]; 
  System.out.println(exp);
  
  if (!exp.contains("/"))
   break;

  }
  

 }`

Comment: @ZubairNabi This will return `(x-2))` as the second result, and would return an incorrect result for `1 / x + 2` because it doesn't take operator precedence into account.

Answer (score 1):

A division is an expression of the form `a / b`, where a and b may be numbers, variables or expressions in their own right. `a` is the "dividend", `b` is the "divisor". You want to output every divisor in the expression.

The key to this is to realize that an expression is actually a binary tree structure. The nodes of the tree are symbols, which combine two sub-expressions. The leaves (nodes with no descendants) are variables or numbers. Here's an example for your expression:

[image: expression tree]

The top operation is the division that happens last. On the left is the `x + 2`, which consists of two leaf nodes (x and 2) combined with a + operation. On the right is the sub-expression (1 + 1 / (x - 2)). Note that the last part is tricky. You might misinterpret it as (1 + 1) / (x - 2) if you just look at the operators from left to right. But it's really 1 + (1 / (x - 2)), because you need to take operator precedence into account.

What you need to do then is create a parser that builds the tree in memory, taking into account the parentheses and operator precedence. If you want all divisors, you can go through every node in the tree and if it's a division node you ask for the expression of its right-hand child. The parentheses have to be filled back in, or you can cache parts of the string during parsing and link those parts to the nodes.

This isn't an answer providing ready-made code, but as stated in the comments, Stack Overflow isn't the place for that. Code may be provided if a very specific question is asked, but for a larger problem like this we prefer explaining the "how", and leave the actual implementation to you. Since that's your job, homework or hobby anyway.